# Tap event not triggered when button is contained within Commandbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have realized that the following XAML no longer works.
I have even attempted to swap the command property for a Tapped property.
Yet, the method handler for the tapped event still does not get called.

It is when I move the appbarbutton outside of the commandbar scope, that the Tapped event gets triggered and handled in the code-behind.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Phone" Label="Call" Command="{Binding CallCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"  />

        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

However, if I place  the appbarcommand outside of the commandbar and replace the command binding with a Tapped event method handler in the code-behind then the event gets triggered.

Comment: I ended up creating method handlers for "Click" events instead. That's the workaround.

Comment: Ah dang I didn't see your comment at first, was going to say just throw `ClickMode="Press"` on it or something. Nice :)